# Parse Error while attempting to deploy First React App

Tags: reactjs, parsing, deployment, compiler-errors, web-deployment

I've made my first react app. It works fine in the development server and on codesandbox, but when I try to deploy, I quickly get a parse error. I'm still new and struggling to understand what's gone wrong. Please let me know if you need any other code bits or any other information. I'm just trying to set it up so it will work to display on github for others to view.

```
Failed to compile.

Error: Parse Error: <link font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren|Montserrat&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
 <link id="external-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" media="all">  <script defer src="/Keeper1/static/js/main.0f9e7a4b.js"></script></head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
</body>
```

```
  - htmlparser.js:255 HTMLParser.parse
    [client]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlparser.js:255:15

  - runMicrotasks

  - task_queues:96 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5

  - htmlminifier.js:1282 async minify
    [client]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:1282:3

  - htmlminifier.js:1365 async Object.exports.minify
    [client]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:1365:16
```

Comment: `<link font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;` this doesn't look like a valid HTML. This CSS shouldn't be here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

Original code:

```
<link font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif; href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren|Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Thanks to Konrad's comment, I fixed and it works.

Fixed code:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren|Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
```